# Licensing question regarding no derivatives

Tags: licensing

I am working on a project where I'd like these licensing terms:

- Allow unmodified redistribution, with attribution to the author
- Disallow modified redistribution
- Non-commercial use

Now the CC BY-NC-ND 4.0 license is perfect for this... however, it does not cover any software topics, and CC themselves say that you shouldn't really use the CC licenses for software projects.

So what should you use in a case like this instead? LGPL comes close, but it does allow commercial use. Standard copyright, without a license, also comes close again, but allows commercial use while disallowing redistribution.

BTW, I understand you guys aren't lawyers. But you might have experience with licensing to know what kind of license you should be looking for with my needs.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may redistribute if you attribute in accordance with this license.
2. You may not redistribute under terms that are different from the terms specified in this license.
3. This software may only be used for non-commercial purposes [specify what non-commercial means]

Comment: Are you suggesting making your own license? As has been said by other posts on Programmers, that's a legal minefield.

Comment: That's the only choice you have, if you want something that's not specifically covered by the existing licenses.

Comment: Well, CC BY-NC-ND coveres it, just not specifically for software.